# SCSS Circular Progress Incidator Issue

Tags: html, sass

I am trying to add an extra stage to a 4-step CSS progress indicator and make it a 5-step progress indicator. The existing code is shown below. How can I modify the code to achieve this?

```
.myact__progress-indicator {
  position:relative;
  width:34px;
  height:34px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:2px solid $twe-grey-lightest;
}

.myact__progress-indicator-progress {
    position:absolute;
    width:34px;
    height:34px;
    border-radius:17px;
  clip:rect(0px, 34px, 34px, 17px);
  margin:-2px;

  &:before {
        position:absolute;
    display:block;
    content:'';
        width:34px;
        height:34px;
    background-color:$twe-green;
        border-radius:17px;
      clip:rect(0px, 17px, 34px, 0px);
      transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  &:after {
        position:absolute;
    display:block;
    content:'';
        width:34px;
        height:34px;
    background-color:$twe-green;
        border-radius:17px;
      clip:rect(17px, 34px, 34px, 17px);
      transform:rotate(90deg);
  }
  &.p1 {
    &:before {
        transform:rotate(72deg);
    }
  }
  &.p2 {
    &:before {
        transform:rotate(144deg);
    }
  }
  &.p3 {
    clip:rect(0px, 34px, 34px, 0px);

    &:before {
        transform:rotate(144deg);
    }
    &:after {
        transform:rotate(90deg);
    }
  }
  &.p4 {
    clip:rect(0px, 34px, 34px, 0px);

    &:before {
        transform:rotate(216deg);
    }
    &:after {
        transform:rotate(72deg);
    }
  }
  &.p5 {
    clip:rect(0px, 34px, 34px, 0px);

    &:before {
        clip:rect(0px, 34px, 34px, 0px);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    &:after {
        display:none;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="myact__progress-indicator">
                <div class="myact__progress-indicator-progress p{{r.fields[6].value + 1}}"></div>
                <div class="myact__progress-indicator-inner">
                  <span class="myact__progress-indicator-label">{{r.fields[6].value+1}}/5</span>
                </div>
              </div>
```

P1 and P2 are working as expected but it starts to fall over at P3, I tried to create a fiddle but  I'm unable to replicate, I'm hoping I missed something glaringly obvious.

[image: Progress Indicator P1]

[image: Progress Indicator P2]

[image: Progress Indicator P3]

Comment: Can you post the compiled CSS? And also the compiled HTML that matches the CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to do the rotations correctly, though it doesn’t work as logically expected from a code perspective it renders as expected.